# Localize iOS resource by region, not dialect

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to distinguish between localizations by region and dialect in my app. For example, if I add a localization for "English (United Kingdom)" Xcode adds it under the *language ID* `en-GB` i.e. English as spoken in the UK. But what I really want is a localization for the UK region regardless of the spoken language.

I tried adding the localization under `en-GB` and then manually screwing around in the project file to rename all of those to `en_GB` (which I think is the locale ID for the UK region, regardless of the English dialect) but it doesn't seem to make a difference in the app. For example, if I set my language to "English (U.S.)" and region to "United Kingdom", I still see all of the U.S.-localized versions. Similarly, if I set my language to "English (U.K.)" and region to "United States", I see all of the UK versions.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle), bundle resources are looked up by region before language, so it seems like this should be possible, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nitish that question seems to be about getting iOS to respect regional dialects. I'm not having that problem. I want to see if it's possible to localize based on the user's region even if they pick a different dialect that does not match their region.

Comment: Apologies. I have withdrawn my vote to close.